# Easy way for accessing memcached from node.js

Tags: node.js, memcached

I want to know if there is a good driver or native implementation to connect node.js directly to memcached.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the search on: https://npmjs.org/

If you don't have npm, install it.

On the cli:

> npm search memcache

Brings up 5 modules.

This seems to be the most popular: https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached

Comment: lmgtfy is deprecated. This isn't a feed vs fish question - it's a request, however subjective, on what are good memcached modules. btw npm search <term> is always super slow.

Comment: I found working  demo at https://jsonworld.com/demo/how-to-implement-memcached-in-nodejs-application

Answer (score 36):

Here's my experience of using couple of node-memcached modules

1. [3rd-Eden/node-memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached). The project doesn't seem to be stable and has bugs with storing BLOBS ([see issue #46](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/issues/46) and [issue #48](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/issues/48) for details). Moreover I found it's code quite hard to read (and thus hard to update), so I wouldn't suggest using it in your projects.
2. [elbart/node-memcache](https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache) seems to work fine, and I feel good about the way it's source code is written, but it doesn't support storing BLOBs (there's a [fork](https://github.com/ddopson/node-memcache) that is said to add the ability, but I haven't tested it)
3. [overclocked/mc](https://github.com/overclocked/mc) is the one I like a lot. This is the only one that is capable of storing BLOBs. It has nice documentation, its code looks good and it is easy-to-use.

Currently I use [overclocked/mc](https://github.com/overclocked/mc) in [my project](http://latex.aslushnikov.com) and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: overclocked/mc seems to be at http://overclocked.com/mc and https://github.com/jackyz/mc now

Comment: 'memjs' for the win
https://github.com/memcachier/memjs

Answer (score 11):

The basic idea.

```
net = require("net");

var client = net.connect({port: 11211, host:"localhost"},function() { 
    console.log('connected');

    client.write('stats\r\n');
    //OR other commands + "\r\n"

    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    client.on('end', function() {
        console.log('data fetched');
    });
});
```

Also you can use net.createServer to make your own memory cache server to support additional requirements such as **PERSISTENT YOUR CACHE DATA TO MYSQL**.

Comment: I need to think this way more frequently!