# Storing binary blobs from node.js in memcached

Tags: javascript, node.js, memcached, blob

I have a node.js application that handles dynamic images. At some point I need to cache an image and i'm currently just writing them into files on disk.

I'm considering to replace the file cache with memcached.

So, my question is: Is there a way to store and read binary data to/from memcached using node's streams (ReadableStream/WritableSteam)?

Simplified example of what I want to achieve:

- get data from a URL
- pipe the response stream to memcached
- later read it and pipe it into another http response

**UPDATE:**
I learned that memcached has a fixed size limit on values that can be stored which makes it unsuitable for my use case.

I'll look into other technologies like Redis and see what I can do with that.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so the simple answer to your question is yes. Yes there is a way to store/read binary data to/from memcached using node streams. The "how" is the more difficult part.

NodeJS is an exceptional platform for solving exactly this sort of problem. The benefit of using the Stream system will mean that the node instance will not be using too much memory when relaying the image back and forth from the memcached server, but the age old question presents itself: Is this what you want?

I am not an expert on memcached but given what I know about NodeJS and their [documentation of the memcached protocol](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt) I am sure that given enough time I could write a bespoke stream implementation that perfectly meets my needs... but who ever has the time?

There are a few competing memcached modules, and there is a really good SO answer that gives summary of what the differences are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10430328/690826

That answer suggests the mc module, which at first glance doesn't seem to expose a stream interface and instead it has the more common node callback api. This will have the issue of while a file is being served to a client the full file will be in memory for the duration of that request.

Now, I know I've said this once but I'll say it again: **it all depends on what you need**. If your scenario means that you will be memory bound instead of bandwidth bound then you can either a) try to find/implement a streams based memcached interface or b) parallelise your node endpoints.

This also begs the question do you really need memcached at all? My first approach to this sort of problem would be to implement something like https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-static and see how well your servers/service holds up.

Again this advice is given having literally no knowledge of the size of your application, all of these decisions should really take that crucial fact into account.